# ANTLR4 How can I create a regular expression that allows all characters except two selected ones?

Tags: java, regex, antlr, antlr4

Hi for example I have this code for the g4 file:

```
a: [A-Z][A-Z];
b: [a-z]'3';
```

Now I want to add one line more, which recognizes all characters that do not belong to a or b

I tried:

```
a: [A-Z][A-Z];
b: [a-z]'3';
ALLOTHERCHARACTERS: ~[a]|~[b]
```

But i didn´t work.

For example the input 84209ddjio29 should now be in ALLOTHERCARACTERS, but i didn ´t work.

(The Lexer gives at the end a java file, but I think this is not important to know, for this "task")

Comment: Are you trying in your example to write a regex that would match any character except 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: No any Character except [A-Z][A-Z] and [a-z]'3', for example ALLOTHERCHARACTERS should not catch z3 or AA or BB or b3 but it should catch for example AAAjidej29 or b7 or u9

Comment: Would it not be easer just to search for the two excluded characters.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things going wrong here: inside parser rules, you cannot use character sets. So `a: [A-Z][A-Z];` is not possible. Only a lexer rule can use character sets, so `A: [A-Z][A-Z];` is valid.

So, to define a valid (lexer) grammar, you'd need to do this:

```
A : [A-Z] [A-Z];
B : [a-z] '3';
```

Now for your second problem: how to negate rules `A` and `B`? Answer: you cannot. You can only negate single characters. So negating `A : [A-Z];` would be `NA: ~[A-Z];` (or `NA : ~A;` is also valid). But you cannot negate a rule that matches 2 characters like `A : [A-Z] [A-Z];`.

If you want a rule that matches anything other than upper case letters, lower case letters and the digit 3, then you can so this:

```
ALLOTHERCHARACTERS : ~[A-Za-z3];
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the proper syntax for "anything except":

```
[^ab]
```

so that will match any character that is not a or b.

Comment: No, `[^ab]` is not valid ANTLR syntax