# ANTLR4 How can I create a regular expression that allows all except this two statements // How to delete a part of a input

Tags: java, antlr4

I saw this question:
[ANTLR4 How can I create a regular expression that allows all characters except two selected ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72088870/antlr4-how-can-i-create-a-regular-expression-that-allows-all-characters-except-t)

because of this I thought a little bit about antlr4 (I used antlr years ago).

Now I have a other question for example we would have:

```
A: [a-z]+'ug';
B: [A-Z][a-z]+;
C:
```

Now I want that C recognize all Characters which not belong to A or B.

How we could make this? What would be here the correct regEx?

```
   C: ~[a-zugA-za-z]
```

That would be false or?

I thougth a lot, but without sucess.

---

And a other question is, just for interest.

Now, for example, if I wanted antlr to recognize this for me:

I have e.g. as input:

```
thisisonlyatest/*oidjqiodjqw*/test
```

Now i want to delete all between `/* */`, so that the result is only:

```
thisisonlyatesttest
```

How we could make that?

Or for example the input would be:

```
thisisonlyatest/*oidjqiodjqw*/test
another line /*kjdqio*/ another text
```

the result:

```
thisisonlyatest test
another line another text
```

I tought that we could make:

```
A: ('/*'(.)*'*/')
B: ~A
```

but it didnot work.

Comment: the two questions cannot be answered with one answer ... please post two separate questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A character set `[a-za-z]` is exactly the same as `[a-z]`. And including `ug` in a set that already contains `a-z`: `[a-zug]` is not necessary because the range `a-z` already includes both `u` and `g`. So `C` would just be:

```
C: ~[a-zA-Z]; // note that `A-z` must be `A-Z`
```

W.r.t.:

```
A: ('/*'(.)*'*/');
B: ~A; // No, this is incorrect!
```

As I mentioned in the other question: you cannot negate a rule (`A` in this case) that matches multiple characters. You can only negate rules that match a single character.

If you want to skip comments, just do:

```
COMMENT
 : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
 ;
```

### EDIT

> For example you have the input: AA this should also be at C but it would not work.

That is correct, you said you wanted `C` to recognize "all Characters which not belong to A or B". What you're looking for is probably just this:

```
A: [a-z]+ 'ug';
B: [A-Z][a-z]+;
C: [a-zA-Z]+;
```

That way, lowercase letters ending with `"ug"` would become an `A` token, letters starting with an uppercase will become a `B` token, and all the others will become `C` tokens.

Comment: Thank you! But I think C is false. Because: For example you have the input: AA this should also be at C but it would not work. Because AA would not be correct for A, but also not for B.

Comment: No, in my example C will always match a single char, not AA. You dint quite understand how ANTLRs lexer rules work. I recommend doing some tutorials before going forward.

Comment: Thank you, but [a-zA-z]+ will not recognize a input like &/)() or? Symbols will not be recognize?

Comment: No, `[a-zA-z]` only matches the ASCII range `A` to `z` (hex `0x41` to `0x7A`).